# Image saving as error file (0 bytes) in Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

When I save the image using flask, it saves as a file with 0 bytes

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, url_for
from inference import predict_breed_transfer
import os
import io
from PIL import Image
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = './static'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'}

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'super secret key'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def submit_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            image = file.read()
            predicted_breed = predict_breed_transfer(image_bytes = image)
            imag = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image))
            imag.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            result_dic = {
                'im' : filename,
                'breed' : predicted_breed
            }
            return render_template('index.html', dog=result_dic)
        return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Please help me with this. Also, for your help, this project is hosted at https://dog-identification.herokuapp.com/

The screenshot
[of image properties which is creating after we save image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bz5Pi.png)

Comment: Not familiar with Flask, but I suspect the problem is that after reading the entire uploaded file via `.read()`, `.save()` is only saving what comes after the current file position - which is nothing at all.  You already have the entire file contents in `image`, you can just write that to disk without doing anything further with `file`.

Comment: Thanks, @jasonharper, I have updated the function submit_data(), Now the image is saving with required bytes

Comment: @ArchitGarg please post your updated submit_data() code

Comment: Hello, is this the updated, working, version of the code? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

before saving write:

```
file.seek(0)
```

two line upper, you read the file so you should put curser at first then save it!

Comment: May be you can a bit of explanation as why this works.

Comment: file.seek(offset, whence)

offset − This is the position of the read/write pointer within the file.
whence − This is optional and defaults to 0 which means absolute file positioning, other values are 1 which means seek relative to the current position and 2 means seek relative to the file's end.